# Weighted Averages with Conditional Probabilities

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, weighted-mean, weighted-data

I'm very new to statistics and am trying to learn how to analyse the risk of a therapeutic side effect occurring given different data sources.

For example, I'm trying to calculate the risk of a shared side effect occurring in one individual if two medicines (Medicine A and Medicine B), given they share the same side effects.

What makes it a little more complicated is that there is varying data in the literature for the side effects.

For example, there are 2 studies for the risk of side effects occurring in Medicine A:

- Study 1: 3% (N = 500)
- Study 2: 4.5% (N = 1000)

And for Medicine B:

- Study 1: 4.8% (N=100)
- Study 2: 7.2% (N=150)

The side effect probability is also dose-dependent, which makes it even more complicated.

As I said, I'm new to statistics, so any pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have more than two studies for each drug you might want to meta-analyse them to get the proportion.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

For general information on meta-analysis (MA) you could look at the [tag-info](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/meta-analysis/info). I have not read the sources it quotes so cannot recommend one over another.

The basic MA paradigm is that from each study (on drug A) you extract the statistic you wish to summarise $y_i$ and its variance $v_i$. You then form a weighted average using $w_i=\frac{1}{v_i}$. In your case there is a complication that the proportions take the role of the $y_i$ and they are supposed to be normally distrbuted which they clearly are not. The answer is to transform them first. At this point I strongly recommend choosing a software system to do all this. MA is certainly available in R (which I use), see the [CRAN Task View](http://CRAN.R-project.org/view=MetaAnalysis) for more details I use `metafor` but `meta` also does this, available in Stata (search for Stata metaprop) and in various stand-alone packages. It is possible to program it in SAS but I have no idea how. I have never seen anyone do it in SPSS but it may be possible.

When you have done that you will have an estimate from each set of studies on drug A and on drug B so you can proceed to compute the probability of their simultaneous occurrence conditional on their being independent.